# Puiseux series and Resolution of Singularities

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, singularity-theory

I have a very basic knowledge of algebraic geometry(no schemes!), and am trying to study the resolution of singularities.
So the Newton's method gives us a Puiseux series parametrizing the branches of a curve at a point.
What I do not understand is how this gives a resolution of singularities. Since the Puiseux series is a power series, where is the variety here?
I know this is a basic question, but most of the references skim through this aspect and make it sound self-evident. I am hoping for some simple explanation of the connection. Thanks!

Comment: what are these "most of the references" you do not mention? If you tell us where you did look it is easier to give you useful references!

Comment: "Lectures on Resolution of Singularities" by Kollar describes the Newton's method, but does not explicitly describe how the Puiseux series provides a resolution of singularities. Another reference by  Cutkosky on the same topic mentions it in passing as a corollory of a more complicated result. I was hoping there is a direct explanation in the special case of curve singularities.

Comment: The Puiseux series give directly a smooth parametrization (i.e. a Riemann surface) of a singular curve, you can see Theorem 1 in Section 8.3 and the following remark on page 389-390 of Brieskorn's "Plane Algebraic Curves". If you want to realize this smooth model as a variety, Theorem 9 in Section 8.4 of Brieskorn's book which I mentioned before gives you a method by blow-up processes.